# How can i make custom form module joomla3.x

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

```html
<select name="A">
  <option value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="2">Saab</option>
</select>
<select name="B">
  <option value="1">test1</option>
  <option value="2">test2</option>
</select>
<input type="Submit" >
```

After I submit, I want to show result from A and B.  For example:

```
if($_POST['A']==1 && $_POST['B']==2){ 
   echo 'true'; 
}else{ 
   echo '0'; 
}
```

Is it possible to do this in joomla?

Answer (score 0):

you have to enclosed this input fields into form tag. For example

```
<form method="post">
<select name="A">
  <option value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="2">Saab</option>
</select>
<select name="B">
  <option value="1">test1</option>
  <option value="2">test2</option>
</select>
<input type="Submit" >
</form>
```

Hope it will help